# VSCode Chrome Debugger disable web security

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I'm developing a remote application which need the web security disabled on Chrome, which I have a windows shortcut that takes the following runtime argument:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=C:\Program
```

For vscode, I have the following launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "web-security-disabled-chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8000",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--disable-web-security --user-data-dir=C:\\Program",
                "-incognito"
            ], 
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

and it doesn't disable web-security.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID [https://my.remote.ip/restapp/...
```

I also tried the following:

Give vscode a new directory for user data. I saw the folder got populated, but web-security is not disabled.

Put -user-data-dir into it's own string. VSCode shows error

```
Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000ms -(reason: Can't find a valid target taht matches: about:blank. Available pages: ["chrome-ex...://ceimgagkkofjoalgojpkdcmhmbljbbaa/_generated_background_page.html"]).
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to configure Chrome debugger to run web-secruity-disabled?

Comment: any update on this ?

Comment: Please mark the answer that works. This one works just fine for me: `"runtimeArgs": ["--disable-web-security"]`

Answer (score 2):

For certificate issue, you should add the below command line argument:

```
"configurations": [
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
   ...
  "runtimeArgs": ["--ignore-certificate-errors"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
"runtimeArgs": ["--auto-ssl-client-auth"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I Just added `"runtimeArgs": ["--disable-web-security"]` below config and it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
"configurations": [
{
  ...,
  "runtimeArgs": ["--disable-web-security"],
  "userDataDir": "D:\\MyChromeDevUserData"
}
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a chrome profile, like suggested [here](https://briandesousa.net/2018/05/12/using-a-chrome-developer-profile-with-visual-studio-code-debugger/).

Basically, (1) start chrome once with the profile, (2) accept the certificate and (3) change your launch.json in vscode to something like this:

```
"configurations": [
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
  "url": "http://localhost:4200",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "runtimeArgs": ["--profile-directory=debug-profile"]
}
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are  missing a dash in your attribute, it should be --incognito and it will work.

```
"configurations": [
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
  "url": "http://localhost:4200",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "runtimeArgs": ["--incognito"]
}
```